# PC Monitors - Additional

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a DELL Inspiron 15 (N0150) laptop.

I know I can attach two external Monitors to it, they only display clones of the laptop monitor.

It is running Windows 7, and uses the Intel graphics adapter.

How can I display a different screen on each monitor, so that screens are not cloned?

Comment: What operating system is on your laptop?

Comment: Why do you mention TV in the title but not in the description?

Comment: Steve I hope this gets to you, but I cannot work out how to respond. I have edited the question. I am using Win 7 Ultimate with Intek Graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Try right-clicking on the desktop, and click on "Screen Resolution". It should show you the monitors that are connected to the laptop. If your computer has the ability to extend the desktop rather than duplicate it, then you should see a drop-down labeled "Multiple displays" with options like "Duplicate these displays", "Extend these displays", "Show desktop only on 1", etc. You want to select "Extend these displays".